# Client Certificate using Weblogic

Tags: java, ssl, client, certificate, weblogic

Background:
 I am working on a project that involves the client to authenticate itself (via client certificate). We are trying to launch a third party app which first authenticates the client cert and then launches its app.
We are using Java and SSL hanshake, and our client server is Weblogic 10.x. The client certificate is in PKCS12 format (cannot change this)
This is the piece of code for presenting the certificate:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","MyPath/cert.pfx");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","MyPwd");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","PKCS12");
url.openConnection();
```

Now all this works pretty well from a standalone. The problem starts when we put this on weblogic. Sometimes it works, sometimes 'Client certificate not present' (http 403.7) is returned. I have tried various combinations (including configuring custome keystore on weblogic console) but nothing seems to work. Any idea why would weblogic altogether ignore the SSL settings (it doesnt throw an error even if I set keystore to a non-existent file)? System.setProperty for SSL just appears useless on weblogic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution! Weblogic seems to over-ride the keystore configurations if it is done through Java as above. The thing that worked for me was to configure the SSL settings on JVM level, at web-logic start-up. 
To make it work, I just added these Java options in the start-script for weblogic:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=MyPath/cert.pfx
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=MyPwd
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=PKCS12
```

Restarted web-logic and SSL has been working great since then :)

Answer (score 4):

In Weblogic 12c you also need add the parameter **`-DUseSunHttpHandler=true`** in order to tell the weblogic server to use the Sun Http Handlers instead of its own. Therefore you need the following Java VM parameters:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=MyPath/cert.pfx
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=MyPwd
-DUseSunHttpHandler=true
```